# changing template crops the images on powerpoint slides

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint

I have many powerpoint slides that violates accessibility standards and need to be fixed. I've managed to fix many of the problems by using a new template. But I've noticed that when I apply the new template, the images in the slides get cropped.

Here's the normal uncropped without the new template applied. https://www.mediafire.com/file/4nivoztss6g7lhj/normal_uncropped.pptm/file

edit: added pptx file instead
https://www.mediafire.com/file/cjs3phgv3yu77bs/normal_uncropped.pptx/file

and here's the same file with the new template applied
https://www.mediafire.com/file/38z7x49x8v5q2oi/cropped.pptx/file

how do I fix this so that applying the new template doesn't change the dimension of the picture or the cropping?

I really need help here. I have so may of these files, and I can't teach without fixing these because it's against the law, and I didn't make the files. And I have no alternatives because that's an open educational resource file.

thank you for any insight.

Comment: You might have more responses if you'd save both files as PPTX. Some people won't be able to open PPTM files due to security settings; some won't open them from an unknown source due to common sense.

Comment: edited to include a new pptx file

Comment: Thanks. In the original, do you know how the photo came to be narrower than the placeholder itself, rather than filling it "wall to wall" as would normally be the case?

Comment: in the normal file, the picture fills the place holder. in the cropped version with the new template applied, it gets cropped. look at fig 2.2 I have no idea how it got to be that way. and i have no idea how the original one has wall-to-wall filling in the place holder.

Comment: I tried a variety of things but didn't get anywhere with it either ... sorry.

Comment: thank you for your efforts